# Disable Vuetify v-touch in a child element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify and I want to execute some code when the user swipes left or right. I have a container like this:

```html
<div
    v-touch="{
      left: () => next(),
      right: () => back()
    }"
  >
<!-- other html -->
</div>
```

The problem is that this container has another element, whose text has to be scrolled horizontally. On the phone, when I swipe to scroll this text, the swipe is captured also by the container v-touch directive and it goes next even if it shoud not. How can I say to do nothing if that child is swiped? Is there a target parameter or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the touch events on the element you want to exclude so that the `v-touch` directive doesn't get the events if they happened on or inside the element you want to exclude.

```html
<div
  v-touch="{
    left: () => next(),
    right: () => back()
  }"
>
  <div
    @touchstart.native.stop
    @touchmove.native.stop
    @touchend.native.stop
  >
    ...non swipable content
  </div>
  ..swipable content
</div>
```